# How to lock cell from updating via IMPORTHTML at 12:00 PM that day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm importing weather data from accuweather into google sheets using 
`=IMPORTHTML("https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/chicago-il/60605/january-weather/26461_pc?monyr=1/1/2019&view=table","table",1)`

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyAK7.png)

Accuweather has their website setup to remove the Forecast column when the day ends, I would like for the forecast to stay on the sheet to use the descriptive data for logging purposes.

Could someone help me with a method to do this?

Here is a sample of the sheet I'm using.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W3KMwE2dEqe0dkoggKJ5LRT3qHEgwD71izVKx8gJn08/edit#gid=1329106762

Weather data is originally pulled into the Settings sheet, from there it is pushed out to the other sheets depending on the day.
I would like the forecast to stick on the other sheets when today comes at 12:00 PM CST instead of pulling the empty forecast that accuweather generates at EOD.

I'm trying to add a Forecast Log column, if it could pull the Forecast from Column E daily until 12:00 PM that day I could achieve what I'm trying to do.
Having some trouble with the formula, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the formula by it's result. In order to do this automatically near of the specified time you could use a time-driven trigger.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers

#### Time-driven triggers

> A time-driven trigger (also called a clock trigger) is similar to a cron job in Unix. Time-driven triggers let scripts execute at a particular time or on a recurring interval, as frequently as every minute or as infrequently as once per month. (Note that an add-on can use a time-driven trigger once per hour at most.) The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m., then keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours elapse before the trigger fires again.